# Replace decimal values with zero decimal value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Lets say I have a number `2,65,563.56` in a particular cell. I want excel to automatically change it to `2,65,563.00`.
I could simply format the cell to display the integer part of the number only making the decimal part disappear but I want the decimal part to show as `.00`

Please note, I don't want excel to round off the number as it might alter the integer part of my number. Hence I would like excel to simply replace the non-zero decimal value (`.56`) with a zero decimal value (`.00`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [FLOOR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/floor-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886) is the way, and you can specify the `significance`:

```
=FLOOR(value, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  Aside from floor there is also:

```
=ROUNDOWN(value,0)

or

=INT(value)

or

=value-MOD(value,1)

or

=LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)*1
=LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)/1
=LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)+0
=--LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)
NOTE: the math operation at the end and the leading -- turns the text back into a number.
```

If you do not need the value as a number useable in formulas you could also do:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)&".00"
```

[image]

Note:  With the exception of the text option, you will have to adjust the format of the cells to display 2 decimal accuracy as under general cell format, leading and trailing zeros do not display.  With the text option you may need to adjust cell justification to suit your needs.